# Add rows when values in columns are equal in df

Tags: r

For a sample dataframe:

```
df <- structure(list(animal.1 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 
                                        4L, 3L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("cat", "dog", "horse", "rabbit"), class = "factor"), 
                 animal.2 = structure(c(1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 
                                        1L), .Label = c("cat", "dog", "hamster", "rabbit"), class = "factor"), 
                 number = c(5L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 1L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 11L)), .Names = c("animal.1", 
                                                                                  "animal.2","number"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                             -10L))
```

... I wish to make  a new df with 'animal' duplicates all added together.  For example multiple rows with the same animal in columns 1 and 2 will be put together. So for example the dataframe above would read:

cat cat 16

dog dog 7

cat dog 3 etc. etc... (those with different animals would be left as they are).  Importantly the sum of 'number' in both dataframes would be the same.

My real df is >400K observations, so anything that anyone could recommend could cope with a large dataset would be great!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be to use `data.table`.  Convert "data.frame" to "data.table" (`setDT(`), if the "animal.1" rows are equal to "animal.2", then, replace the "number" with `sum` of "number" after grouping by the two columns, and finally get the `unique` rows.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[as.character(animal.1)==as.character(animal.2), 
               number:=sum(number) ,.(animal.1, animal.2)]
unique(df)
#    animal.1 animal.2 number
#1:      cat      cat     16
#2:      cat      dog      3
#3:      dog      dog      7
#4:      dog   rabbit      1
#5:   rabbit   rabbit      4
#6:   rabbit      cat      6
#7:    horse      cat      7
#8:      cat  hamster      1
```

Or an option with `dplyr`.  The approach is similar to `data.table`.  We group by "animal.1", "animal.2", then replace the "number" with `sum` only when "animal.1" is equal to "animal.2", and get the `unique` rows

```
library(dplyr)
  df %>% 
     group_by(animal.1, animal.2) %>% 
     mutate(number=replace(number,as.character(animal.1)==
                                    as.character(animal.2),
     sum(number))) %>% 
     unique()
```

Comment: Why not simply `df %>% group_by(animal.1, animal.2) %>% summarise(number = sum(number))` ?

Comment: @StevenBeaupre`  This was the same thing I discussed with David Arenburg.  The solution works as long as there are no duplicates for different animals in the two columns

Comment: @StevenBeaupré  Create a new row with `cat dog 4` and then try with this approach and the one in the post.

Comment: It's clear now. Sorry for having you repeat yourself. +1

Comment: @StevenBeaupré  Thanks for the comment.  But, I could be wrong too (about interpreting the OP's description) as two brilliant persons suggest the same thing.